# How to get a text response with requests in Python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

Here is my code `requeststest_.py`

```
response = requests.get('https://example.com/thenumber.json')
testnumber = 1

print('it works') if testnumber == response.text else print("doesn't work")
```

Here is `thenumber.json`

```
1
```

What I want the code to do is return "it works", meaning, how do I get the response.text as a number? When I do `print(testnumber)` and `print(response.text)`, they both return 1 as an integer

How do I get them to be equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, all I had to do was replace `response.text` with `int(response.text)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert text to integer.
For exaple:

```
print('it works') if testnumber == int(response.text) else print("doesn't work")
```